# React Native cameraWithTensors onReady is not being called

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

I'm trying to capture camera stream using cameraWithTensors from tensorflow/tfjs-react-native example from https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.2.3. I'm using react-navigation button tabs (do not know if this is related).

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { cameraWithTensors } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

class MyComponent {

  handleCameraStream(images, updatePreview, gl) {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value

      console.log("*** This line is not logged ***");

      // if autorender is false you need the following two lines.
      // updatePreview();
      // gl.endFrameEXP();

      requestAnimation(loop);
    }
    loop();
  }

  render() {
   // Currently expo does not support automatically determining the
   // resolution of the camera texture used. So it must be determined
   // empirically for the supported devices and preview size.

   let textureDims;
   if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1920,
      width: 1080,
    };
   } else {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1200,
      width: 1600,
    };
   }

   return <View>
     <TensorCamera
      // Standard Camera props
      style={styles.camera}
      type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
      // Tensor related props
      cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
      cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
      resizeHeight={200}
      resizeWidth={152}
      resizeDepth={3}
      onReady={this.handleCameraStream}
      autorender={true}
     />
   </View>
  }
}
```

Using the following modules

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.4

"expo-gl": "^8.1.0"
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "1.7.2",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.2.3",
"core-js": "3",
"expo": "^36.0.2",
"expo-asset": "~8.0.0",
"expo-camera": "^8.2.0",
"expo-constants": "^9.0.0",
"expo-font": "~8.0.0",
"expo-gl": "^8.1.0",
"expo-image-picker": "^8.1.0",
"expo-permissions": "^8.1.0",
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.1",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
```

Tried on iOS simulator and device as well. "OnReady" function is not being called or any console is logged. On app startup I got these errors:

1. > Initialization of backend rn-webgl failed
2. > Error: ExponentGLObjectManager.createContextAsync: Unexpected error
   >   occurred when initializing headless context

I tried to debug the react native app got no clue on the root cause of this. It can be a dependency issue. When I use [this simple example](https://dev.to/amanhimself/image-classification-on-react-native-with-tensorflow-js-and-mobilenet-dpc) it works fine, however, when trying to use the same component as a screen tab it fails.

I'd appreciate if you explain how to resolve these errors above.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, after a few days of digging this out. The dependencies are not the issue here.
Probably if your app.json app name contains spaces for some reason the bundled js is not loading correctly.
The error

> Initialization of backend rn-webgl failed

as it said your webgl backend failed to load. On some devices, webgl is not supported. I used iPhone X iOS 13 and it seems that webgl 1 & 2 are supported correctly. This is the graphics engine that allows leveraging GPU for complex computations. 
When using expo need to make sure your react-native version matches your expo client (0.61.X supported with the current expo client), otherwise, you will get an exception on app load. 
Second error (Error: ExponentGLObjectManager.createContextAsync: Unexpected error occurred when initializing headless context) is a result of the error above.
The bottom line, need to make sure your index.js, app.json we well as metro caches are aligned and fresh. 
To clear metro cache use

```
rm -fr $TMPDIR/metro* & watchman watch-del-all
```

Then

```
rm -fr node_modules
```